# Multible Angular Applications in Spring Boot Project

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project and several Angular applications. These angular applications are completely different. Currently I have both in a separate folder under /static. Furthermore I have a controller with two get interfaces that calls the index.html of the applications. But the scripts are not called in the browser (this mean the angular apps dosn't run).
Is it possible to load the two applications correctly?

```
     -java
        -package
            - controller
                   -Controller.java
         -Application.java     
     -resource
        -static
           - app1
           - app2
```

The Controller Code:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {


@RequestMapping(value = "/appone", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
public String appOne(){
    return "/appone/index.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/apptwo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
public String appTwo(){
    return "/apptwo/index.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in package.json, under the build command the flag --deploy-url. This must be named like the base url, the folders in the public folder and like the REST endpoints in the controller.