# Run Spring Boot backend and multiple frontends on same Tomcat

Tags: angular, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I have only a single Tomcat server available and need to run the following:

- A Spring Boot service providing CRUD operations on a DB via REST API
- 2-3 different Angular frontends consuming the REST API

I only found guides explaning how to provide a single Angular frontend as static ressource within the WAR.

But what is the best approach to handle two or even more frontends on one Tomcat along with the Spring Boot service as in my case?

Can this be solved using Maven modules?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can deploy each application as a separate war.

Comment: Check this out -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672453/multible-angular-applications-in-spring-boot-project

Answer (score 0):

if you want resource isolation , many different Angular frontends can't put a SpringBoot application.

why not try Nginx.

Comment: I can't, I must use the Tomcat - there really is no way for one backend with more than one frontends in Tomcat?

Comment: maybe use path isolation , put it in resources folder. like below  
├─first
├───aa.js
├───aa.css
├─second
├───bb.js
├───bb.css